# Uploading Package Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, publish

I'm proud to say that I finished my first app and now I want to publish it to google play. When I try to upload the signed apk it gives me an error saying my package name is incorrect (com.example.xxxxxxx). I tried renaming it by going to android tools -> rename package name but it won't work. I don't know how to name it and even if i do (org.android.xxxxxxx) nothing happens. Could someone explain this to me?

Also, since I'm already asking...could someone tell me how do I add ads to my app?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the name of your package ? Does it respect the hierarchy of your project ?

Comment: Check out AdMob to add ads

Comment: Name of the package is com.example.gw2legendaries, google play says the package can't start with "com.example"...so how should I rename it?

Comment: Er, how should someone answer this?  It can't begin with "com.examole".  How about "com.somethinguniquetome.com"?

Comment: That's what I was aiming for yes, I wasn't sure if there are any "rules" to name your package. So now I simply went for "com.<my dev name>.<app name>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package name should be something individual to you. "com.example" and "org.android" are default namespaces which are already taken by the system.

"com.<:your company name:>.<:app name:>" would be a good alternative.

Secondly, advertisements can be added to your activity by importing the advertising library. Admob is owned by google and is a good platform to begin with. Instructions on how to do that are found here: http://www.google.com/ads/admob/

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Perfect!